# Set up a repository for docker

Tags: repository

I'm trying to set up a stable repository from which to install docker:

```
coleman@coleman-XG41:~$ sudo add-apt-repository \"deb[arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \stable"
>
```

Can anyone see a problem with it?

Comment: Why have you escaped the `"`?

Comment: I don't understand your question?

Comment: You have put  a backslash ``\`` before the first quote `"`. Why?

Comment: coleman@coleman-XG41:~$ sudo add-apt-repository "\deb[arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \stable"
[sudo] password for coleman: 
Error: '\deb[arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \stable' invalid
coleman@coleman-XG41:~$

Comment: I think you were right about the quotation mark's position

Comment: ... but still no cigar.

Comment: Why exactly are you adding ``\`` in the command at all?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know.  I am just copying

Comment: What are you copying from?

Comment: You were correct about \   The following is correct:                                      sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"

Comment: ttps://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#set-up-the-repository

Comment: is what I was copying from

Comment: Found the correct command on digital ocean how to install docker on ubuntu